# python telegram.ext commandhandler not working with list of commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use a list of commands with the commandhandler but the appropriate function never gets called.

```
getabList = ["getab"]
for x in range(0, 31):
    getabList.append("getab%03d" % (x,))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(getabList, self.getab))
```

Only when defining a single command it will call self.getab

The idea is having a list of commands that already include the parameter in the command itself when sending a telegram message because then I can just click the command within the message instead of entering the parameter manually. e.g.  /getab030 vs /getab 030
Or is there a way within a telegram message to make "/getab 030" a link?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "making  '/getab 030' a link" ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way of adding a command to the `CommandHandler`

`CommandHandler('command string', command_to_execute)`

Or for your example

`CommandHandler('getab', self.getab)`

First argument is the string that will trigger the command in the bot, second is the function to execute. You can also use a 3rd argument - `pass_args=True` to let the bot know this command is followed by arguments, and handling them in the function.

If you don't want to use `pass_args` you can let the user call a generic command like `/getab` and make the bot prompt the user with a keyboard of options that, when clicked, execute appropriate commands with the value the user picked.